# Would it be a good idea to use a TRIAC as a crowbar in this application?

Tags: triac

The idea here is to sense when the electrodes of the transformers secondary make contact which would be sensed by the optocoupler and trigger the SCRs to switch ON the transformer for spot welding. This circuit would go in series with one of the cables from the secondary.

I am correct, the TRIAC being the resistive load would get HOT and fail before a spot weld would ever happen.

Is there a better option to replace the TRIAC and short thos lines when spot welding.
[image]

Comment: Some context would be helpful to those of us unfamiliar with arc-welding. Crowbaring a supply is usually done to blow the fuse / circuit breaker. (The term comes from third-rail electric railways where a linesman could throw his crowbar between the live and running rails to trip the supply circuit breaker in an emergency.) A bit of explanation about the ACS device and a hyperlink might be in order. Where are the electrodes? Where is the transformer? Why not connect up the various parts of your schematic?

Comment: it would indeed help if you would say what "this application" actually is.

Comment: This is a independent circuit and it goes in series with one of the cables of a MOT used in spot welding 18650 cells. The ACS is a allegro current sensor (https://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&itemSeq=265523089&uq=636666867615678756) and the TRIAC (http://www.ween-semi.com/documents/BTA440Z-800BT.pdf). Cable from the MOT connects with AC1 and continues with AC2 with an electrode at the end. The other end of the cable has another electrode.

Comment: I could not think of another/better solution than using the TRIAC to bypass the current. Is there any component that could do this ?

Comment: (1) Please put all the relevant information into the question rather than sprinkled through the comments. (2) Your link for the ACS narrows it down to 8,272,849 results. Can you give a direct link? (3) If the ACS is a current sensor then it implies that it's on a low resistance cable. If that's true then how would the triac affect the circuit? (4) What is an MOT?

Comment: The current sensor is a Allegro ACS7703CB-200B (https://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&itemSeq=265523089&uq=636666867615678756) the link is provided from digikey. Yes the cable is a 3AWG thick. A MOT is Microwave Oven Transformer.